# CKEditor plugin button disabled in source mode

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, toolbar

I was trying to add my own toolbar button in CKEditor (inside vBulletin). Following is my Code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'app',
{
init: function( editor )
{
    editor.addCommand( 'AppWidget',
        {
            modes : { source : 1, wysiwyg : 1 },
            exec : function( editor )
            {   
                alert("foo");
            }
        });
    editor.ui.addButton( 'app',
    {
        label: 'App Widget',
        command: 'AppWidget',
        icon: this.path + 'app.png'
    } );
}
} );
```

Problem is: It will show in WYSIWYG mode, but will be disabled (greyed out) in source mode. But I need this button to be enabled in source mode. If I write:

```
modes : { source : 1 },
```

it will be disabled in both modes.

Any hints on this here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved. I noticed the editor mode should be:

```
modes : { enhancedsource : 1 }
```

Comment: Where do you add this configuration option? Is there a particular file?